# Custom format to display percentage with plus/minus sign

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, conditional-formatting

Suppose I have cell value `0.465` and I want to display it in the spreadsheet in green as `+46.5` if it is positive and `-46.5` if it is negative. I have applied the following format

`[Green]+0.00%;[Red]-0.00%`

but MS Excel changes this format to `[Green]+#.000%;[Red]-#.000%` and displays the value as `+046%`. I have tried [other formats](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=199687) without success. Any ideas?

- MS Office Professional 2010 (Excel v14.0.7128)
- Libre/OpenOffice is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested this on Excel 2013:

```
[Green]"+"0.00%;[Red]"-"0.00%
```

NOTE: actually my excel is in another language with different decimal separator, so it looks like this:

```
[Green]"+"0,00%;[Red]"-"0,00%
```

but I assume yours use the dot as decimal.

Comment: Thanks! You reply actually spotted the problem: in my environment the decimal separator is also `,` but I was totally misled by pre-cooked build-in custom formats. And yes, quoting signs originally didn't help – I've tried that as well.